# Breaking ties at random, is the rank of an element of an exchangeable vector uniform on $1,\ldots,n$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, random-variables

Say we have an exchangeable vector $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ in which ties are possible. Say we compute the rank ($1$ being hte largest) of the elements by breaking ties at random, i.e. the rank of $2$ in the vector $(5,2,4,2,-1)$ is $3$ or $4$, each with probability a half. Is it true that the rank of $X_i$ is uniform on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ for all $i$? Here is my attempted proof!

We first define the rank function as follows: First let 
$R(X_i,(X_1,\dots,X_n))\in \mathcal P(\{1,\dots,n \})$, where $\mathcal P$ denotes the power set, so that if there are no ties, and $X_i$ is the $i-$th ranked element ($1$ being the largest, $n$ being the smallest) then $R(X_i,(X_1,\dots,X_n))=\{ i\}$. If there are ties, we do the following. Say there are $j$-larger elements, and $k$ ties, then $R(X_i,(X_1,\dots,X_n))=\{j+1,\dots,j+k \}$. As we want to break ties at random, we define $C: \mathcal P(\{1,\dots,n \}) \to \{1,\dots, n\}$ to take a uniformly chosen element from a set, independently of everything else.

Now by exchangeability, for any $\pi \in S_n$, $$(X_i,(X_1,\dots,X_n))\stackrel{d}{=} (X_{\pi(i)},(X_{\pi(1)},\dots,X_{\pi(n)}))$$ and thus also 
$$R(X_i,(X_1,\dots,X_n))\stackrel{d}{=} R(X_{\pi(i)},(X_{\pi(1)},\dots,X_{\pi(n)})). $$
Now by definition of the rank function 
$$R(X_{\pi(i)},(X_{\pi(1)},\dots,X_{\pi(n)}))=R(X_{\pi(i)},(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})), $$
where we use that the order of the vector argument of $R$ does not change the value of $R$. Thus
$$R(X_i,(X_1,\dots,X_n))\stackrel{d}{=} R(X_{\pi(i)},(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})). $$
Lastly, applying the function $C$ to both sides,
$$C(R(X_i,(X_1,\dots,X_n)))\stackrel{d}{=} C(R(X_{\pi(i)},(X_1,\dots,X_n))).$$
This proves that the rank of each entry has the same distribution. So the probability each of the $n$ elements is ranked $k$ is the same, and as these probabilities need to sum to 1, each has probability $1/n$.

I'm looking to see if you believe the result is true or not, if there's any mistakes in this argument or if there are nicer ways to prove this or a textbook which has this result.

Comment: In your example you state that the rank of 2 in vector (5,2,4,2,-1) is 3 or 4. Don't you mean that it is 2 or 4?

Comment: I mean that, if $v=(5,2,4,2,-1)$, then $R(5,v)=\{1\}$, $R(4,v)=\{2\}$ and $R(-1,v=\{5\}$ and $R(2,v)=\{3,4\}$ and then $C$ chooses a random element, so $3$ wp $1/2$ and $4$ wp $1/2$. Sorry if this is unclear!

Comment: $C$ doesn t seem a function if I understand correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but you can prove a more general result more easily: The result is a random permutation of the indices. Since both the distribution of the $X_i$ and the distribution of the tiebreaks are invariant under permutations of the indices, all permutations of the result are equally likely. Thus, in particular, each value of the rank is equally likely for each index.